# purging the boost::pool_allocator for a std::map does not return the whole pool in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, pool, stdmap

When I run the next code in VS2017:

```
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Map = std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, boost::pool_allocator<std::pair<const int, int>>>;
    using Pool = boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(Map)>;

    Map temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) temp[i] = i;

    std::cout << "First addresses:\n";
    for (auto& kv : temp) std::cout << &kv.second << "\n";

    temp.clear();
    Pool::purge_memory();

    Map temp2;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) temp2[i] = i;

    std::cout << "Second addresses:\n";
    for (auto& kv : temp2) std::cout << &kv.second << "\n";

    temp2.clear();
    Pool::purge_memory();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
First addresses:
02A108F4
02A1090C
02A10924
02A1093C
Second addresses:
02A1090C
02A10924
02A1093C
02A10954
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/QKOAW37657)

This behavior seems incorrect: what happened to address `02A108F4`? It seems it was not returned to the pool during the purge.

This doesn't happen when I use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::map`.
gcc also seems to return the memory correctly: [Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mPXrGAOvz9idEq6I).

Is this a bug in VS2017?

Comment: In your added live example, the behaviour doesn't occur.

Comment: Yes, that's what I say: In GCC, the live example, it works. In VC++ it doesn't. I will add a live example of VC++

Comment: Live sample MSVC: http://rextester.com/BWANL51397

Comment: I was writing all that up as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming things about the implementation details of the pool. You may well be right there is a loss, but you can't conclude this from the allocation patterns you see.

Also, you're purging the memory for the pool allocator associated with `sizeof(int)`. However, the value_type is already `std::pair<int const, int>`, and that leaves the fact that the map implementation allocates an unspecified node-type instead.

> Oh, and the reason your allocator worked is precisely the same: the container implementation *knows* you cannot possibly provide the right type of allocator, since the allocated type is unspecified. Therefore it will always [*rebind* to get the required type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

So, at least make it

**<kbd>[Live On Rextester](http://rextester.com/EQGCO3082)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using Map = std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, boost::pool_allocator<int>>;
using Pool = boost::singleton_pool<boost::pool_allocator_tag, sizeof(Map::value_type)>;

void foo() {
    Map temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) temp[i] = i;

    std::cout << "First addresses:\n";
    for (auto& kv : temp) std::cout << &kv.second << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    Pool::purge_memory();

    foo();
    Pool::purge_memory();
}
```

This, though is still assuming implementation details. I *think* c++17 gives you some more information to work with (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) or otherwise you could see wheter Boost Container has the relevant details: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/container/map.html#id463544-bb

Comment: I had just added a note about that in the answer. We keep being an our tails :)

Comment: Ah, but now in my example, where I have two maps `temp` and `temp2` ,the same issue occurs again. Even with your modifications. [Live example](http://rextester.com/PPVV44433). I'm not using delete, I'm using `purge`, so all memory should be returned, right?

Comment: I think `std::map` stores extra stuff using the allocator when creating an object. But that only happens in VC++ and not in GCC it seems.

Comment: I think you need to want the first sentence again. That was _aside_ from the obvious allocator size mismatch. See this: http://rextester.com/WIWYK11486 If you observe closely it's only the first element that gets a /slightly/ displaced address there. The other nodes coincide with the addresses of the first run. You can't really reason about this. If you must have the control, consider object_pool (avoiding the singleton pools) or intrusive containers e.g.

Comment: Re: "stores extra stuff" - that might be (although I don't think that is conformant?) and you could try to [disable debug iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx) or other runtime library extras

Comment: OK, but then back [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50508905/6717178), where I found this issue. How can I use the `pool_allocator` for an `object_pool`?

Comment: @JHBonarius in that case I don't see the issue with std::map doing minor allocations on the side. If it does http://rextester.com/IFF93902 ?

Comment: I bumped into some extra information, from "the horses' mouth" explaining the lingering allocation after `clear()`, when not destructing the `map`: https://twitter.com/CoderCasey/status/1005578618578325506 (be sure to read the whole thread)